# Accuracy remains constant after every epoch

Tags: keras

I Have created a model to classify plane and cars images bu after very epoch the acc and val_acc remains same

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as plt
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Convolution2D
from keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.preprocessing.image import image
import os 

model=Sequential()
model.add(Convolution2D(32,(3,3),input_shape=(64,64,3),activation="relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(2,2))
model.add(Convolution2D(64,(3,3),activation="relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(2,2))
model.add(Convolution2D(64,(3,3),activation="sigmoid"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(2,2))
model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(32,activation="sigmoid"))
model.add(Dense(32,activation="sigmoid"))
model.add(Dense(32,activation="sigmoid"))
model.add(Dense(1,activation="softmax"))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy',
               metrics=['accuracy'])
 train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True)
```

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'train_images',
        target_size=(64,64),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='binary')

test_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'val_set',
        target_size=(64,64),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='binary')

model.fit_generator(
        train_set,
        steps_per_epoch=160,
        epochs=25,
        validation_data=test_set,
        validation_steps=40)

```
Epoch 1/25
30/30 [==============================] - 18s 593ms/step - loss: 7.9712 - acc: 0.5000 - val_loss: 
7.9712 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 2/25
30/30 [==============================] - 15s 491ms/step - loss: 7.9712 - acc: 0.5000 - val_loss: 
7.9712 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 3/25
30/30 [==============================] - 19s 640ms/step - loss: 7.9712 - acc: 0.5000 - val_loss: 
7.9712 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 4/25
30/30 [==============================] - 14s 474ms/step - loss: 7.9712 - acc: 0.5000 - val_loss: 
7.9712 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 5/25
30/30 [==============================] - 16s 532ms/step - loss: 7.9712 - acc: 0.5000 - val_loss: 
7.9712 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 6/25
30/30 [==============================] - 14s 473ms/step - loss: 7.9712 - acc: 0.5000 - val_loss: 
7.9712 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 7/25
30/30 [==============================] - 14s 469ms/step - loss: 7.9712 - acc: 0.5000 - val_loss: 
7.9712 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 8/25
30/30 [==============================] - 14s 469ms/step - loss: 7.9712 - acc: 0.5000 - val_loss: 
7.9712 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 9/25
30/30 [==============================] - 14s 472ms/step - loss: 7.9712 - acc: 0.5000 - val_loss: 
7.9712 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 10/25
30/30 [==============================] - 16s 537ms/step - loss: 7.9712 - acc: 0.5000 - val_loss: 
7.9712 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 11/25
30/30 [==============================] - 18s 590ms/step - loss: 7.9712 - acc: 0.5000 - val_loss: 
7.9712 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 12/25
30/30 [==============================] - 13s 441ms/step - loss: 7.9712 - acc: 0.5000 - val_loss: 
7.9712 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 13/25
30/30 [==============================] - 11s 374ms/step - loss: 7.9712 - acc: 0.5000 - val_loss: 
7.9712 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 14/25
30/30 [==============================] - 11s 370ms/step - loss: 7.9712 - acc: 0.5000 - val_loss: 
7.9712 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 15/25
30/30 [==============================] - 13s 441ms/step - loss: 7.9712 - acc: 0.5000 - val_loss: 
7.9712 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 16/25
30/30 [==============================] - 13s 419ms/step - loss: 7.9712 - acc: 0.5000 - val_loss: 
7.9712 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 17/25
30/30 [==============================] - 12s 401ms/step - loss: 7.9712 - acc: 0.5000 - val_loss: 
7.9712 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 18/25
30/30 [==============================] - 16s 536ms/step - loss: 7.9712 - acc: 0.5000 - val_loss: 
7.9712 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 19/25
30/30 [==============================] - 16s 523ms/step - loss: 7.9712 - acc: 0.5000 - val_loss: 
7.9712 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 20/25
30/30 [==============================] - 16s 530ms/step - loss: 7.9712 - acc: 0.5000 - val_loss: 
7.9712 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 21/25
30/30 [==============================] - 16s 546ms/step - loss: 7.9712 - acc: 0.5000 - val_loss: 
7.9712 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 22/25
30/30 [==============================] - 15s 500ms/step - loss: 7.9712 - acc: 0.5000 - val_loss: 
7.9712 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 23/25
30/30 [==============================] - 16s 546ms/step - loss: 7.9712 - acc: 0.5000 - val_loss: 
7.9712 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 24/25
30/30 [==============================] - 16s 545ms/step - loss: 7.9712 - acc: 0.5000 - val_loss: 
7.9712 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 25/25
30/30 [==============================] - 15s 515ms/step - loss: 7.9712 - acc: 0.5000 - val_loss: 
7.9712 - val_acc: 0.5000
```

Comment: This happens because the model is not learning. The gradients in the intermediate layers are same. Any reason why you are using `sigmoid` in the intermediate layers instead of `relu`  ?

Comment: Actually it's because of the softmax. While using binary_crossentropy  we should use sigmoid.

Comment: And while using sigmoid instead of relu,the model will learn but the accuracy will be around 50%

Answer (score 1):

You have several issues in your model structure.

- First of all, for the output of your model

`model.add(Dense(1,activation="softmax"))`

You are using a softmax, which means you try to solve a multi-class classification, not a binary classification. If it is really the case, you need to change your loss to `categorical_crossentropy`. In this way the compile line will turn into:

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy',
               metrics=['accuracy'])
```

If it is not the case and you want only solve a binary classification, you might be good, but I do suggest to change the last layer activation to `sigmoid`

- Second: That is a bad idea to use `sigmoid` as the activation in the middle layer since it can easily cause the gradient to vanish (read more [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-fix-vanishing-gradients-using-the-rectified-linear-activation-function/) ). Try to change all the `sigmoid` activation in the middle layer with wether `relu` or even better with `leakyrelu`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is exactly here:

```
model.add(Dense(1,activation="softmax"))
```

You cannot use `softmax` with one neuron, as it normalizes over neurons, meaning that with one neuron it will always produce a constant 1.0 value. For binary classification you have to use `sigmoid` activation at the output:

```
model.add(Dense(1,activation="sigmoid"))
```

Also it is not wise to use `sigmoid` activations in hidden layers, as they will produce vanishing gradient problems. Please prefer `ReLU` or similar activations.